# Data Read from AWS Redshift(Encrypted-->Decrypted) into Power bi takes too much time & fails to load

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

We are trying to read from a Redshift View into Power bi. The redshift view has 40 columns in which 20 of them are PII, they were encrypted in the base table, and the DB team had to apply masking policies to each of the 20 columns to de-crypt the data.

When we try to read it from power bi desktop using the Redshift connector, The preview loading time is around 15 minutes. And once we close and apply, if we are using direct query, it takes forever to load the columns into a simple table visual..the data load is very slow and as more the columns are added, the visual failes with "unexpected error".

I also tried to first select a slicer and limit to single select, and add the table next, and once i start adding the columns into the table visual, which is already filtered on the slicer, it still takes lot of time and fails on me.

Data Volume: 10.5 million rows. If decrypting logic comes into account, then 10.5 million * 20 = 200 million(power bi read).

What i want to know, is there a better way to do this? Did anyone read decrypted data from redshift into power bi in such data volumes?  Appreciate any help. TIA

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but you might want to check https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2022/03/21/6620/power-query-m-primer-part24-query-folding-ii

Comment: One thing I've done with a *different* type of encryption, is that I did everything I could with the raw encrypted values, made a unique list encrypted values I needed minus entries within table of cached decryptions, got those decryptions, and added the 'missing' decryptions to the cached table. Once that process was completed, decrypting is just joining against this two-column table of cached decryptions. (Warning: This results in a cache of table decryptions and some may be PII you no longer need. Depending on your needs, this is either fine or ***completely*** inappropriate.)